# validate in array laravel using .*

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I try to validate in array by using 'id_s.*' => 'required', not sure why t didnt work

**UPDATED** I add my jquery append , in my controller I use loop which I want to require id_s

In my html

```
   <select id="custom-select" class="form-control custom-select" name="id_s[]" >
    <option disabled="true" selected="true" name="id_s[]" value="choose">choose</option>
    @foreach($subject as $s)
  <option value="{{$s->ID}}" name=id_s[]>{{$s->NAME}} / {{$s->CREDIT}} </option>
  @endforeach
</select>



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-form').click(function() {
        i++;
        id_i++;                     
        $('#add-me').append(
            '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+
            '<select id="custom-select" name="id_s[]" class="form-control custom-select"><option disabled="true" selected="true" name="id_s[]" value="choose">choose</option>@foreach($subject as $s)<option value="{{$s->ID}}" name=id_s[]>{{$s->NAME}} / {{$s->CREDIT}}</option>@endforeach</select>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td>'
            +'<button id="'+i+'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delegated-btn">Delete</button>'
            +'</td>'
            +'</tr>'
            );

        $('button.btn.btn-danger').click(function() {
            var whichtr = $(this).closest("tr");
            whichtr.remove(); 
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Can't you just do `'id_s' => 'required'` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue you are having?

Comment: id_s working only 1st item

Comment: I want to validate id_s[] in an array but after I use  'id_s.*' => 'required' it skip my validate

Comment: What do you mean 1st item? It's an array, `id_s` is only one item, it just contains other data. Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: I updated assume that I've and array data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the select you will not need to do array in the name and you don't need to add name to the options as well :

```
<select id="custom-select" class="form-control custom-select" name="id_s" >
    <option disabled="true" selected="true" value="choose">choose</option>
    @foreach($subject as $s)
        <option value="{{$s->ID}}" >{{$s->NAME}} / {{$s->CREDIT}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

and the validation like this :

```
'id_s'  => 'required|not_in:choose'
```

Comment: you mean `$subject` ?? if yes ==> then yes it will

Comment: The best choice is to name evry select with a different name then add a rule for the second one :)

Comment: I try to add value ="choose" but I use name="id_s[]" It work only 1 st data If I add 1 st data and my 2data is empty It skip my validate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157503/discussion-between-maraboc-and-test1321).